# Azure data lake - read using Python

Tags: python, azure, azure-data-lake, azure-databricks

I am trying to read a file from Azure Data lake using Python in a Databricks notebook.
this is the code I used,

```
from azure.storage.filedatalake import DataLakeFileClient

file = DataLakeFileClient.from_connection_string("DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=mydatalake;AccountKey=******;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net",file_system_name="files", file_path="/2020/50002")

with open("./sample.txt", "wb") as my_file:
    download = file.download_file()
    content = download.readinto(my_file)
    print(content)
```

The output I get is 0. Can you some point what I am doing wrong. my expectation is to print the file content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [from_connection_string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-file-datalake/azure.storage.filedatalake.datalakefileclient?view=azure-python#from-connection-string-conn-str--file-system-name--file-path--credential-none----kwargs-) method returns a `DataLakeFileClient`, you could not use it to download the file.

If you want to download a file to local, you could refer to my below code.

```
import os, uuid, sys
from azure.storage.filedatalake import DataLakeServiceClient

service_client = DataLakeServiceClient.from_connection_string("DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=***;AccountKey=*****;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net")

file_system_client = service_client.get_file_system_client(file_system="test")

directory_client = file_system_client.get_directory_client("testdirectory")

file_client = directory_client.get_file_client("test.txt")

download=file_client.download_file()

downloaded_bytes = download.readall()

with open("./sample.txt", "wb") as my_file:
    my_file.write(downloaded_bytes)
    my_file.close()
```

If you want more sample code, you could refer to this doc:[Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-directory-file-acl-python).